# Json.NET: Write response from controller in chunks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have a controller that sends a large payload of JSON data to a mobile app. In some cases that data payload is large - over 10 megabytes. We're running into issues with data limits in our app, though, so I need to find a way to split the data into smaller payloads.

We're using Json.NET to serialize our data. My current solution right now is (a hack) to check the size of the JSONResult that we'd send back; if it's larger than a threshold, the controller will page the result. I've figured out how I can get the size of the response, but I haven't figured out how I'm going to split that response into multiple payloads using Json.NET.

I've looked at Json.NET streamWriter, but it looks as though you have to program that manually (and I already have strongly-typed objects due to the deserialization). Is there a way to split a JSON payload with Json.NET?

Comment: over 10MB JSON data to a mobile app? oO

Comment: It's a sync thing, unfortunately. If the app hasn't synced before, it has to grab the full dataset in order to store it locally.

Comment: Did you turn compression on your web server ? JSON when compressed should be 5+ times smaller. Problem still remains but compression can help.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you change it to work the same as you would a web page ... you wouldn't show a table in a web page with 10Mb worth of data, so the same applies here. So, the idea would be to implement **paging** in your REST API.

So, the first request for data can return the data in sets of pages and include a link to the next page of data when there is some:

A `GET` to `/api/sync` may give:

```
{
    "count": "10",
    "total": "141",
    "next": "/api/sync?page=2"
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "101",
            "date": "2013-02-14"
        },
        {
            "id": "102",
            "date": "2013-02-18"
        }
        // More data here ...
    ]
}
```

Your syncing code can read the first page, see the `next` property has a url, and so repeat the process:

A `GET` to `/api/sync?page=2` may give:

```
{
    "count": "10",
    "total": "141",
    "next": "/api/sync?page=3"
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "111",
            "date": "2013-02-14"
        },
        {
            "id": "112",
            "date": "2013-02-18"
        }
        // More data here ...
    ]
}
```

I hope that helps. The fields or workings of the pagination will probably be different, but it gives a lot of control to you in the syncing process. The most recent data can be loaded upfront and the rest can go in the background, leaving the app functional in the meantime.

Comment: Nice usage of hipermedia link in REST.

Answer (score 0):

any chance to shorten the property names? I had once a similar problem when sending XML to the SQL server and the SQL server ran out of memory. By just using one character for the tag names helped to reduce the size by 80%

Comment: Not without changing our app significantly, no. Although, that may be something we look at in future. (However, doing that will make things much less readable, unfortunately.)

Comment: sorry. this post should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I think works as answer @AcidJunkie - it's something to try. Using compression would do the same thing on the wire, but it would still be 10Mb on the device, so reduction needs to be somewhere if it has to be one payload.